# Python - Possible to rename xml.etree.ElementTree.iter() for 2.6 backward compatibility?

Tags: python, elementtree

I'm writing a script that is going to be run on machines that have either python 2.6 or python 2.7.  The script parses and loops through installed.xml like this:

```
tree = ET.parse('installed.xml')
root = tree.getroot()
for package in root.iter('package'):

        if 'foo' in package.attrib['id'].lower():
            for property in package.iter('property'):
                if 'cic.info.version' in property.attrib['name']:
                    version = property.attrib['value']
```

This works fine on 2.7, but in 2.6 I get and error - _ElementInterface instance has no attribute 'iter'
I've figured out that in 2.6 the method is called 'getiterator', so I was wondering if there is a way to assign an alias to the method, something like this..

```
if cur_python < req_python:
    xml.etree.ElementTree.iter() = xml.etree.ElementTree.getiterator()
```

I tried a few things that I found on here, but couldn't get anything working yet.  Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: `xml.etree.ElementTree.iter() = xml.etree.ElementTree.getiterator()` doesn't work, and `xml.etree.ElementTree.iter = xml.etree.ElementTree.getiterator` doesn't either. You'd have to do that for each instance (`root` and `package`). Maybe define a wrapper and change your code...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you could do that, but you'd have to create the assign for *every* instance:

```
root = tree.getroot()
if cur_python < req_python:
    root.iter = root.getiterator
```

(note the lack of parentheses, we don't want to *call* the function but to define a name). Do the same for `package`.

Or define a wrapper function which returns the correct function:

```
def compat_iter(obj):
    return (obj.getiterator if cur_python < req_python else obj.iter)
```

that you use like this:

```
for package in compat_iter(root)('package'):
...
  for property in compat_iter(package)('property'):
```